# VBA Loop goes beyond threshold

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to master a basic loop using predefined row and column count.

Somehow loop continues beyond the column limit I have defined for it. Can you advise why? And how can I ensure it does not go beyond column 5?

Below is VBA code:

```
Sub Loop101()
    
Dim r       As Integer
Dim c       As Integer
    
'Loop through rowcount and columncount as defined by r and c variables
r = 3
c = 5
    
'loop which i expect to populate a value of 100 in every cell starting with row 1, column 1 and ending and row3, column 5.
For r = 1 To r
    For c = 1 To c
    Cells(r, c).Value = 100
    Next c
Next r
        
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't use your end point as your loop variable. What does happen in your set up?

Comment: ^ `c` will increase to `6` and then `7` because you're doing that. The first time the inner loop runs, it's equivalent to `For c = 1 to 5`. On the next iteration of the outer `For` loop, it's equivalent to `For c = 1 to 6`, because when the inner loop "finished" the last time, `Next c` incremented `c` to `6`.

Comment: @BigBen, for a newbie like me, can you help me understand WHY next iteration of outer For loop it becomes equivalent to For c=1 to 6? Didn't i limit at 5? Are there any additional threads you can refer me to so i better educate myself around it?

Comment: I literally gave you an answer :-). Because of the `Next c` (or just `Next`, the `c` is redundant). At the end of the loop, the `Next c` increments `c`\ from `5` to `6`.

Comment: @BigBen, thank you. Now i got it.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, don't use your end point as the looping variable.

The code is doing *exactly* what you told it to though, here's an example demonstrating the issue:

```
Dim c As Long
For c = 1 To 5
    ' Do something
Next

Debug.Print c '<= returns 6, not 5!
```

Because you have "re-used" `c` as the end point of the loop, `For c = 1 to c` successively becomes equivalent to `For c = 1 to 5`, then `For c = 1 to 6`, then `For c = 1 to 7`.

**TO FIX IT:**

```
Dim i as Long
Dim j as Long

For i = 1 To r
    For j = 1 To c
        Cells(i, j).Value = 100
    Next j
Next i
```